question about pulleys
Hello I have a question about whether a 385 dc motor with four 1 cm diameter pulleys will be able to lift 3kg.
So it is my understanding that a 385 dc motor has max torque of 150g/cm and 10,000 rpm which I'd also like to verify please.
The height of the rope from the first pulley to the second one is 27 cm however I'm assuming that it should be 54cm in order to go through the four pulleys.
So if the torque is 150g/cm and a 54cm rope is connected to four 1cm diameter pulleys will it be able to lift a 3kg weight?

Is the motor directly turning one of the pulleys?

No. The rope initially goes in the surface of the spinning disk and goes along the four pulleys.

"The spinning disk"?!? You didn't mention that before. What is it?

Based on what you have said so far, no.
"Four pulleys" implies that the weight is distributed over 4 strands of rope, so you have 3000/4 = 750 grams pulling on each strand. If the motor is driving a pulley with a 0.5 cm radius, it can only extert 150/0.5 = 300 grams of pull. So you're off by a factor of at least 2.5.
... and you'll need at least 27 × 4 = 108 cm of rope.

Thank you @Dave Tweed sorry I couldn't upvote the answer. It says I don't have enough reputation points.
